# zlib support for PIL won't work

Tags: software-installation, python, libraries

I'm trying to install PIL as per its instruction on debian but can't figure how to fix this bit:

I get --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available on build_ext
and *** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed on selftest

what am I missing?

```
root@portman:~/dist/Imaging-1.1.7# python setup.py build_ext -i
running build_ext
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.2+ (default, Dec  1 2011, 01:55:02)
              [GCC 4.6.2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
root@portman:~/dist/Imaging-1.1.7# python selftest.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
--- JPEG support ok
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
--- 57 tests passed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL is already packed for Debian in the `python-imaging` package: `apt-get install python-imaging`.

If you really want to install it manually, you maybe need to install the zlib1g-dev package.

Comment: I did install it: root@portman:~/dist/Imaging-1.1.7# dpkg --get-selections|grep zlib1g-dev
zlib1g-dev                                      install

Comment: the reason I'm not installing via python-imaging is because I want to make sure I get all jpeg/zlib etc supported.

Comment: I though this could be because of libz.so being "lost" but that doesn't seem to be the case, too: root@portman:~/dist/Imaging-1.1.7# ldconfig -p|grep libz.so
        libz.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
        libz.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so
        libz.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libz.so

Comment: setup.py looks not at the right positions for the libraries.  `python-imaging (1.1.7-4)` in Debian testing/sid contains a patch ( http://paste.debian.net/15886 ) which fixes the bug with disabled options (jpeg,zlib,...)